# Getting the URL from items in a ContentList field

Tags: jss

What is the best way to get the url for each item added to a `ContentList` field?

Right now, I only get `fields` and `id`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are running in "connected" or "integrated" mode, right?
By default the `MultilistFieldSerializer` responsible for the multilist field serialization (what the `ContentList` ultimately becomes after app import) does not serialize `url` and I believe was done to make the serializer more efficient.

You have two options:

1) Use integrated GraphQL to reshape the datasource data that comes out of the component, see more about the feature here: https://jss.sitecore.net/docs/techniques/graphql/integrated-graphql#integrated-graphql-in-jss-apps

2) Extend the default `MultilistFieldSerializer` and add `url` to the list of serialized fields.

I'd explore the first option first, since it would not require any .NET coding or changes to the configuration.

BTW, I had filed a similar issue in GitHub as well: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/issues/69

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.
Is there is way to extend "js version" of `MultilistFieldSerializer`, so url is populated automatically in the mock data?

Comment: this should work if you add the `url` property on the item your content list field is referencing for disconnected development and the mocked layout service should return it. If you are using YAML for your route data, add `url: /path/to-your-item` in there next to `id` or `name` properties (not within the fields). This will work for you in the disconnected (mocked) environment, but it won't do anything for when the app is integrated so the `url` property would be lost unless your back-end dev extends the `MultilistFieldSerializer`. Pls DM me on Twitter if this doesn't make sense @alexshyba.