# Get URL for route item from Content List field

Tags: jss, typescript

I have a field with a ContentList / Treelist of pages, each one of which I want the URL for.

Using JSS with Next.js.

If I inspect the field in the browser I can see the URL listed for each item as part of its data:

```
js
    "id": [etc],
    "url": "/[etc]/Content-Page",
    "name": "Content Page",
    "displayName": "Content Page",
    "fields": {
        etc.
    }
```

However, if I use the `Item / Item[]` type within my code, the *Typescript* definition for these only has properties for name, display name, and fields.

The code still works fine though if I ignore this error - the URL is there.

Should I be accessing the URL for Content List items in a different way?

I have read this similar question here [Getting the URL from items in a ContentList field](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14698/getting-the-url-from-items-in-a-contentlist-field) which gives some options.

I guess my main point is do I need to try something like that or just cast to a different typescript type?